# how to add pass additional information about Exception, using Enterprise Library ExceptionManager?

Tags: logging, enterprise-library

I've got WCF Service, it has Exception Policy, like

```
[ExceptionShielding("WCFErrorHandling")]
    public class Service : IService
{
   public void Oepration1(long userId)
    {
        try
        {
           //Logic here
        }

        catch (BusinessException ex)
        {
            throw new FaultException<BusinessFault>(new BusinessFault() { Message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
}
```

`BussinesException`, is my class, which can be extended, with property `userId`.
In `Global.asax`, i have `ExceptionManager`

```
ExceptionManager mgr = fact.CreateManager();
            ExceptionPolicy.SetExceptionManager(mgr);
```

So, then `BussinesException` is thrown, everything is fine, I can put userId into `BussinesException` constructor, at `throw` moment, but when occurs Exception of type:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
```

userId field, can't be added, because `TargetInvocationException` is build in Exception. I can overwrtie it, but my project has too many Exceptions.
So, I need to know, userId in every exception, what would you reccomend to me?